# Heap overflow during Nativescript application build on MacOS

Tags: node.js, macos, nativescript

World

I'm developing mobile application using Nativescript, most latest version.

Android build is OK.

But iOS is pain in the back for me.
I'm constantly receiving heap overflow. Tried to set more heap memory for node...
Mac Mini with 8GB RAM.
Just upgraded do 16GB - no change.

```
nrtc63-99:zplapp nrtc63$ export | grep NODE
declare -x NODE_OPTIONS="--max_old_space_size=12192"
```

Tried also other values starting including 8192 and dashes `--max-old-space-size`.

Build log...

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

[1535:0x102d4e000]   314170 ms: Scavenge 4078.7 (4103.3) -> 4078.0 (4103.3) MB, 11.8 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.356, current mu = 0.326) allocation failure 
[1535:0x102d4e000]   314179 ms: Scavenge 4078.9 (4103.3) -> 4078.2 (4103.5) MB, 9.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.356, current mu = 0.326) allocation failure 
[1535:0x102d4e000]   316720 ms: Mark-sweep 4080.1 (4104.7) -> 4077.1 (4104.3) MB, 2537.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.318, current mu = 0.280) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

    0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x1009ce0f9]
Security context: 0x02b2663408d1 <JSObject>
    1: SourceMapConsumer_allGeneratedPositionsFor [0x2b20af167f9] [/Users/nrtc63/WebstormProjects/zplapp/node_modules/@babel/core/node_modules/source-map/lib/source-map-consumer.js:~178] [pc=0xe56ee1564df](this=0x02b2a7e50051 <BasicSourceMapConsumer map = 0x2b2c76e1b39>,0x02b2b5295e01 <Object map = 0x2b2c76e1099>)
    2: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x...

FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: 0x1011bdf85 node::Abort() (.cold.1) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: 0x10009d119 node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: 0x10009d27f node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: 0x1001de7b7 v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: 0x1001de757 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: 0x100364225 v8::internal::Heap::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: 0x100365a7a v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: 0x1003624fe v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: 0x1003602b0 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: 0x10036c0da v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithLightRetry(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: 0x10036c161 v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: 0x10033a5ea v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: 0x100689068 v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: 0x1009ce0f9 Builtins_CEntry_Return1_DontSaveFPRegs_ArgvOnStack_NoBuiltinExit [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: 0xe56ee1564df 
16: 0x100953aa4 Builtins_InterpreterEntryTrampoline [/usr/local/bin/node]
17: 0x1009e01ec Builtins_ArrayForEach [/usr/local/bin/node]
Executing webpack failed with exit code null.
```

Memory utilisation for node process grows up to 4.3GB and then heap-overflow is raised.

[image: Activity monitor details screenshot]

Comment: Check for memory leaks in your code and fix them. Setting --max_old_space_size is not the solution here.

Comment: @kavigun memory leaks during build? in JS?